# NetLogo: sum of list

Tags: list, netlogo

I'm trying to create memory for each turtle (I have two breeds). Depending on color of the breed 1 with which breed 2 interacts, the turtle adds to the memory 0 or 1. Eventually I summarize the list to create certain probabilities. Here is the memory initialization procedure:

```
ask turtles [
 let j 0
    set memory []
    while [j < N] ; N is the size of memory
    [ 
      let actions (list random 2)
      set memory fput actions memory
      set j j + 1
    ]
  ]
```

Here is the memory update procedure:

```
let actions []
    ifelse [color] of target = red [set actions (list target 1)][set actions (list target 0)]
    ask self [
       set memory fput actions memory  
       set memory remove-item N memory
       ]
    ifelse [color] of self = red [set actions (list self 1)][set actions (list self 0)]
    ask target [
       set memory fput actions memory  
       set memory remove-item N memory
       ]
]
```

Eventually, I try to create reporter with command such as:

```
report sum (memory / N) ; N is the size of memory
```

Memory appears to be always zero. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean:

```
(sum memory) / N
```

or just:

```
mean memory
```

And if you want to look at a random turtle's memories to see if it looks like you expect:

```
[memory] of one-of turtles
```

Or to see all of the turtles' memories:

```
[memory] of turtles
```

If all of the turtles have a memory of `0`, then I think the problem is in code you aren't showing. The code you've posted looks fine to me.

Comment: That's right I meant (sum memory) / N, but the memory procedure doesn't work. Memory is shown as zero.

Comment: I can only repeat that the problem isn't in the code you posted; it must be somewhere else.